# How can I find the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, pseudoinverse

I am trying to find Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of the following matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0 & c\\
   0 & 1 & c
  \end{bmatrix}$$

where $c \in \Bbb R$. I found the following:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 1-c &-c \\
-c & 1-c \\
1 &1
\end{bmatrix}$$

But this is not something that I am looking for. I am wondering how standard solver solve this problem, for example, for $c=4$. All online solvers give me this:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
   0.5152 & -0.4848\\
  -0.4848 &  0.5152\\
   0.1212 &  0.1212
\end{bmatrix}$$

Does any body have any idea? Also, do you know a solver that accepts letter as input to calculate the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix that you were given has $3$ columns and $2$ rows and therefore its Moore-Penrose inverse shall have $2$ columns and $3$ rows. Actually, it is this matrix:$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{c^2+1}{2 c^2+1} & -\frac{c^2}{2 c^2+1} \\ -\frac{c^2}{2 c^2+1} & \frac{c^2+1}{2 c^2+1} \\ \frac{c}{2 c^2+1} & \frac{c}{2 c^2+1}\end{bmatrix}.$$This follows from the fact that, if $A$ is your matrix, then it has full rank and therefore its Moore-Penrose inverse is $A^t(AA^t)^{-1}$.